# Посылать от Понтия к Пилату — ошибка?

Tags: фразеология

Возник такой вопрос к уважаемым форумчанам. В русском (и не только) языке существует выражение *посылать от Понтия к Пилату*, основанное на эпизоде в Священном Писании, где римский наместник Понтий Пилат послал Иисуса к правителю Галилеи Ироду Антипе для разбирательства, а тот отправил его обратно, и означающее всякую волокиту, "отфутболивание" человека от одного начальника к другому, вместо того чтобы быстро решить дело.

В различных источниках, например в книге **Библейские фразеологизмы в русской и европейской культуре** Дубровиной К. Н., написано, что этот фразеологизм родился из-за ошибки: якобы люди подумали, что Понтий Пилат не один человек, а два — Понтий и Пилат, которые Иисуса посылали друг к другу. Никаких подтверждений этой версии не приведено.

То есть преобразование цепочки *Понтий [Пилат] посылает Иисуса к Ироду -> Ирод посылает Иисуса к [Понтию] Пилату* в более короткую *Понтий посылает к Пилату* называется ошибочным, случайным.

Мне такая теория кажется как минимум спорной, ибо я вижу тут некую игру слов, цель которой — придать выражению значение зацикленности, рекурсии, бесполезности, а не просто утомительных странствий по инстанциям.

Собственно вопрос. Как вы считаете, выражение *посылать от Понтия к Пилату* основано на ошибке или намеренной игре слов и почему? Спасибо за ваши мнения!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я думаю,  что ОТ ПОНТИЯ К ПИЛАТУ это просто намеренная игра слов с указанием на ненужную зацикленность,  - сам автор вопроса [[@Пересвет](/users/1997/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82)](/users/1997/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82), похоже, склоняется к такому же выводу. Это типа, как *переливать* ИЗ ПУСТОГО В ПОРОЖНЕЕ.

Ошибка не может тут иметь место: любой верующий (и даже неверующий) достаточно хорошо знает, что *Понтий Пилат* это одно лицо, а не два - *Понтий* и *Пилат*. А причиной появления такого каламбура, на мой взгляд, послужила нетипичность именования римского наместника. Обратим внимание на библейские имена - они, как правило, *однословные*. Среди ветхозаветных персонажей (я, лично, знаю) только два *двухъсловных* имени: Иисус Навин и Иуда Маккавей. В Новом Завете их несколько больше: сам Иисус Христос, Иоанн Креститель, Мария Магдалина (т.е. из города Магдала), Иосиф Аримафейский (т.е. из Аримафеи), апостолы  - Иуда Иаковлев (т.е. брат Иакова), Иуда Искариот (т.е. сикарий = человек с ножом), Симон Зелот (зелоты это иудейские партизаны против римской власти). Как видим, *двухъсловные* новозаветные имена употребляются ради того, чтобы не путать двух апостолов Иуд, Иоанна Крестителя с апостолом Иоанном (Богословом), Марию Магдалину с Марией Богоматерью, Иосифа Аримафейского с плотником Иосифом, мужем девы Марии. Причём вторая часть имени это типа как прозвище с географическим или качественно-личным указанием, а не родовая фамилия. А тут вдруг Понтий, да ещё Пилат, как буд-то существовал какой-то другой Понтий, не-Пилат. Или другой Пилат, не-Понтий. И ПИЛАТ это не географическое название, и не личное качество носителя имени. Такая нетипичность именования прокуратора Иудеи, с использованием составного имени (имя + фамилия), судя по всему, и породила несколько шутливое к нему отношение и создала почву для каламбура. К тому же  обе части имени  -  ПОНТИЙ и ПИЛАТ  - начинаются на П. Я  другого объяснения не вижу.

Примечание: исторически, римский наместник Понтий Пилат был не прокуратором (как ошибочно в евангельском тексте), а префектом Иудеи.

Answer (score 1):

Подтверждений версии мы и не найдём. Где бы их взять... Мне кажется объяснение вполне приемлемым. Правда, по его подобию в народе ходит уже и "От Карла к Марксу", что говорит о восприятии фразы как "от тебя ушло - к тебе и вернётся", т.е. "никто, кроме тебя самого , не решит". Но это осмысление, а там речь об этимологии. Одну и ту же фразу мы воспринимаем и объясняем по-разному, не зря же появляются новые значения старых слов. Язык развивается,а ошибка вполне возможна.

Comment: Этимология должна как-то обосновываться. В этом выражении есть явная ирония, которая часто сопровождает десакрализованные библейские фразеологизмы ("лить елей", "одним миром мазаны", "Лазаря петь", "злачные места" и пр.), и мне кажется, что она неслучайно появилась. 

Что касается "От Карла к Марксу", то тут я вижу то же значение — зацикленность. Грубо говоря, должны идти вперёд, а ходят от Карла к Марксу, от Маркса к Карлу.

Answer (score -1):

потому что понтий - это море, а пилат-это лоцман.  потому и посылают с корабля за пилотом, чтоб в порт войти.

Comment: И в чём смысл выражения в таком случае?

Comment: Думается, это шутка моряков.  А все на полном серьезе обсуждают. Смешно, но в бенгальском лодка-naukā-নৌকা  корабль-jāhāja, а в венгерском-hajó, наверное кроме библии есть еще куда более интересные темы.